# What's the fastest way to get a video frame count in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video-editing

Paging through a video with 1423 frames (192X1080 resolution) consumed 63 seconds using this code:

```
vidObj = VideoReader(videoname);
nFrames = 0;
while hasFrame(vidObj)
    readFrame(vidObj);
    nFrames = nFrames + 1;
end
```

Loading the same video returned a frame count in a mere 4 seconds.

How can the video frame counting be sped-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is fetch the [`NumberOfFrames` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html#busqe2j-1-NumberOfFrames) from the `VideoReader` object:

```
vidObj = VideoReader(videoname);
nFrames = vidObj.NumberOfFrames;
```